# Absolute Offset Percentage + Value?

Tags: css, position, width

Is it possible with css' absolute positioning element to do something like:

```
 .myElement{
    width: 385px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50% - 385px;
 }
```

and have the element offset by a percentage minus its width, or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a negative margin in the direction you want to go.

```
.myElement{
    width: 385px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
     margin-left: -385px;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use calc:

```
.myElement{
width: 385px;
position: absolute;
left: **calc(50% - 385px)**;}
```

it's pretty much supported->
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc